# Can we use smartGWT to non-GWT apps?

Tags: selenium, gwt, selenium-ide, smartgwt

I'm really new to automation testing and would appreciate some jump start.

I am using Selenium IDE and added SmartGWT extension. Will we be able to get this to work to non-GWT applications?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, in which language you want to write your application?

Anyway, at the core of SmartGWT there is [SmartClient](https://www.smartclient.com/product/smartclient.jsp), which is a JavaScript library. 
Since SmartClient is JavaScript, you can include it in any software you want to write, for example in TypeScript or pure JS.

If you are looking into testing a GWT application, then you don't have to worry. Once compiled a GWT application is just JS, that you can run and test with any tool you'd like.

Comment: A program, website, is given and I'm not sure if this is a  GWT application. In case this is not a GWT app, will I be able to use SmartGWT  to test this? I'm working on java.